# How can we increase throughput on the LUIS programmatic API?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

When using the LUIS programmatic API, we get frequent 429 errors ("too many requests") when doing a half-dozen GET and POST requests. We've inserted a pause in our code to deal with this.

We have a paid subscription key to LUIS, which indicates we should get 50 requests/second (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/language-understanding-intelligent-services/). However, it seems the paid subscription key can only be used for hitting the application endpoint. For `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` in request headers, we must use our "programmatic key", which is associated with the Starter_Key, which is (apparently) rate-limited.

Am I missing something here? How do we get more throughput on the LUIS programmatic api?

[image: LUIS Keys]

[image: LUIS Programmatic Key is same as Starter Key]

Answer (score 0):

One of our engineers arrived at the following answer, so I'm going to post his answer here.

The programmatic API is limited to [5 requests per second, 100K requests per month](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-resources-faq#what-are-the-transaction-limits-on-the-authoring-api) for everyone. Your paid subscription key is only for the endpoint API, not for the programmatic API.

If you need more throughput:

1. Put  your API requests in a queue. It is unlikely that you need to update your LUIS model non-stop, 5 times per second -- you probably just have a burst of updates. Put them in a queue to stay within the limit.
2. Don't try using the same user account to manage multiple LUIS models. Set up additional accounts for each model, which gives you additional programmatic keys. Each programmatic key gives you 5 requests per second.